# Find node inside el

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have in backbone instantiated view like

```
var m=new StyleModel();
m.set({"test":"test"});
var a=new StyleView({"model":m,"el":$("#price")});
```

el is row like

```
<tr id="price">
<td>
<button class=".bold"/>
<button class=".italic"/>
</td>
<td>....</td></tr>
```

how to find nodes for bold and italic ? I need to toggle class to that nodes.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, I think your HTML should look like this:

```
<button class="bold"/>
<button class="italic"/>
```

You don't want the `.` in the `class` attribute, that's for class selectors.

Inside your view, you'll have [`this.$el`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-$el):

> A cached jQuery (or Zepto) object for the view's element.

and [`this.$`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-dollar):

> If jQuery or Zepto is included on the page, each view has a $ function that runs queries scoped within the view's element. [...] It's equivalent to running: `view.$el.find(selector)`.

So you can do either of these:

```
this.$el.find('.bold')   // bold elements
this.$el.find('.italic') // italic elements

this.$('.bold')
this.$('.italic')
```

Or even:

```
$(this.el).find('.bold')
$(this.el).find('.italic')
```

Older versions of Backbone won't have `this.$el` but they will have `this.$`; other than that, it is a matter of personal preference which one you use.